# How to access the fragment's button in an activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

i am creating two java file 1st main activity.java  file 2nd fragment.java file create button on fragment.java how to click listener written on activity.java help me

fragment.java

```
public class fragment extends fragment{
Button btn;
// some code
btn = (Button)layout.findviewbyid(R.id.btn1);

}

}
```

activity.java

```
public class activity extends Activity
{


 // how to access the click action btn here
 btn.setOnclicklistner(new View.OnClickLisitner(){
 public OnClick(){


 }
```

Comment: Hi jai, Please elaborate this question. Then only we are able to answer.

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Comment: i create the button variable fragment class how to click action code write activity class

Comment: its possible or not....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define custom `clickListener` class and create it's `instance` in `fragment` and set listener instance there. Now you can write code in that class. Hope it will help you.

```
public class MyCustomListener implements OnClickListener{

     @override
     public void onClick(View v){

     // you stuff
     }  
}
```

then in your fragment call this

```
MyCustomListener listener=new MyCustomListener();
btn.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: i create the button variable fragment class how to click action code write activity class....

Answer (score 4):

To use the button in activity from the fragment, you have to use `getActivity()`

In your fragment,

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_select, container, false);

        btn = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn);
}
```

*btn is the button in activity*

**getActivity()** in a Fragment returns the Activity the Fragment is currently associated with. (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()).

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take on the issue, both in Java and Kotlin.

Java:

```
public final class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   /***/

   public final void yourMethod() {
      printIn("Printing from yourMethod!")
   }
}

public final class YourFragment extends Fragment {

   /***/
    
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                YourActivity yourActivity = (YourActivity) getActivity();
                yourActivity.yourMethod();
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

Kotlin:

```kotlin
class YourActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    /***/

    fun yourMethod() {
        print("Printing from yourMethod!")
    }
}

class YourFragment: Fragment() {

    /***/

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        button.setOnClickListener {
            val yourActivity = activity as YourActivity
            yourActivity.yourMethod()
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps someone out there =)

Comment: PS. I almost entirely do Kotlin so feel free to polish the Java (or Kotlin) anyway you want to

Comment: PPS. Thanks to @Gerke for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to delegate a button click inside a fragment back to its parent activity.

Keep a reference to the parent activity inside your fragment. Then set the listener to your button in your fragment like this:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        parentActivity.doStuff();
    }
};
```

In your parent Activity, define method `doStuff()`:

```
public void doStuff() {
    // handle button click event here
}
```

Comment: For those who also struggle to get a reference to the parent activity, you need to cast the result of getActivity. 
Example: If your activity is called ExampleActivity you do:
```ExampleActivity activityVariable = (ExampleActivity) getActivity();```

Comment: This was the solution for me!