# how to access main activity button from fragment in android

Tags: java, android

In main activity I have 5 buttons an I have no buttons in fragments how to access those main activity buttons from  fragments. I have total 5 fragments class.

Comment: try to post some code

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27860503/how-to-access-the-activity-button-from-fragment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the activity button from fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27860503/how-to-access-the-activity-button-from-fragment)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the button of YourActivity in the fragment, then you can use **getActivity()** reference.

Make your *buttons as public* in main activity,

```
public Button mybtn;
```

Then in your fragment, Access it by

```
((YourActivity)getActivity()).mybtn
```